# Categorical Variable with too many levels for Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, cart

I am trying to build a decision tree but the problem is I have too many levels on one of my categorical variable. The variable is 'source' - It indicates the source website where the user came from. I want to include this variable in my decision tree. How to deal with the many levels?

Comment: I’m what way is it “too” many? // Is every website different?

Comment: Yes, every website is different and there are many websites from where the users come. Some websites occur very frequently and some are rare.

Comment: “Some websites occur very frequently” seems incompatible with “every website is different”. Could you please explain your comment?

Comment: So not every website is different; there are duplicates. // What do you mean that there are too many? // I wonder how a random effect would work for you.

Comment: In the source column - There are are a lot of websites which occur frequently. Like google.com has a frequency of 179591, youtube.com has a frequency of 50000. But there are a lot of websites which have a frequency of 1

Comment: So what’s the problem?

Comment: I want to one-hot encode this column to use in decision tree

Comment: That’s what I would do. What’s the problem?

Comment: The problem is there are too many different websites and if I one-hot encode them it will make the dataframe too wide

Comment: Why is it too wide?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To *get rid of* high cardinality features, you have options

- Frequency encoding, which encodes the frequencies of the entities instead of their categorical values
- Mean encoding (beware of possibility of overfitting) because you'll be using target information
- Hashing
- and some others.

As a first step, I'd go with frequency encoding, it's simple and less risky compared to mean encoding, and more meaningful than hashing. To calculate website frequencies, use your training data (not testing). You may need to preprocess your data to accommodate for *Other Website* category, since you may have new websites in the test data.

You may also want to use existing architectures like doc2vec, or train separate autoencoders for the websites, but I'd first start simple.

Comment: great summary, even have embedding solution.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved with a 1 or 2 sentence summary of each approach (like you've done with frequency encoding already), and maybe expanding on "some others" and adding some links on top of that. If someone is already familiar with these approaches, they won't find the answer useful because they'll already know the answer. If they're not familiar, they will only find the answer somewhat useful, as they'd need to go and do research by themselves to figure out what you're even recommending.

Comment: @NotThatGuy thanks for the feedback! I'll add details as soon as I have the opportunity

Answer (score 9):

I can think of three strategies:

1. Use a random effects model. This shrinks the predicted outcome for low frequency categories towards the grand mean and is usually the best approach.
2. Group all low-frequency categories into "other"
3. Classify all low-frequency URLs by category and use the categories rather than the URLs; leave higher-frequencies categories as they are

Answer (score 2):

One tactic is finding quantitative characterizations, or at the very least categorical characterizations with fewer levels, of the original levels. The most obvious is mean encoding, but you can try out anything you can think of: length of URL, top level domain name, etc. Take a look at the URLs and see if any categorization occurs to you.

Another tactic is ensemble modelling. Reducing the number of features can increase the number of levels that a model can usefully incorporate, so if you can find subsets of the features that yield useful results, you can build a model for each subset, and then build an ensemble model.

Keep in mind that the more things you throw at it, the higher the risk of overfitting.